# Spring Batch - Transaction markes as rollback only

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

I've a Spring Batch process with JPA and I have this problem:

I have a class with

```
    @Configuration
    public class BeansBatchConfig {

          @Bean(name = "jobRepository")
          public JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepository() {

            this.jobRepository = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            this.jobRepository.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
            this.jobRepository.setTransactionManager(this.transactionManager);
            this.jobRepository.setIsolationLevelForCreate(this.isolationLevelForCreate);
            return this.jobRepository;
          }

The manager:

       @Override
  public void saveProjectCategory(ProjectCategoryEto eto) {

    try {
      this.projectCategoryDao.save(getBeanMapper().map(eto, ProjectCategoryEntity.class));
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
      this.projectCategoryDao.clear();
      LOG.error("Ha habido problemas al insertar el proyecto " + eto.getProject().getCode());
    }
  }
```

And the tasklet that call the manager.
The stracktrace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.capgemini.esr2pon.component.daemon.common.utils.ScheduledTasks.launchProjects(ScheduledTasks.java:86) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

I've tried to pue this code in each method but the result is the same

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=EmptyResultDataAccessException .class)
```

I've think the problem is in the JobRepository but I don't know what I have to change in the Transaction Manager. Any ideas?

Thanks.

UPDATED WITH SAVE METHOD:

```
  @Override
  public E save(E entity) {

    if (isNew(entity)) {
      this.entityManager.persist(entity);
      LOG.debug("Saved new {} with id {}.", getEntityName(), entity.getId());
      return entity;
    } else {
      if (this.entityManager.find(entity.getClass(), entity.getId()) != null) {
        E update = this.entityManager.merge(entity);
        LOG.debug("Updated {} with id {}.", getEntityName(), entity.getId());
        return update;
      } else {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Entity not found");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you show us the findByCode() from DAO layer?

Comment: I've updated the code. Sorry, the method was "save" not "find by code", is the save jpa method. Check again, thanks!

Comment: Show us the implementation of save() method please

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to your problem? I think I'm encountering the same thing :-P.